# MySQL. How to number group's members in JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Example:

```
set @num=0;

select * 
, @num:=@num+1 as num 
FROM 

(SELECT *  from
(select (1) union select (2) union select (3) union select (4) union select (5)  order by rand())a) a

join

 (SELECT * FROM (select (1) union select (2) union select (3) union select (4) union select (5) union select (6) union select (7) union select (8) union select (9) union select (10))c) b
on b.1 >= a.1
```

it returns

```
1, 1, 1
1, 2, 2
2, 2, 3
3, 3, 4
1, 3, 5
2, 3, 6
3, 4, 7
1, 4, 8
4, 4, 9
2, 4, 10
```

and so on...

I need fourth column to be as follows

```
1, 1, 1, 1
1, 2, 2, 1
2, 2, 3, 2
3, 3, 4, 1
1, 3, 5, 2
2, 3, 6, 3
3, 4, 7, 1
1, 4, 8, 2
4, 4, 9, 3
2, 4, 10, 4
```

So, the fourth column is counter from 1.. up to second column in groups

Comment: you could just add it in the client easily enough. fetch a row, append a counter to the row array, boom... counter.

Comment: whats the common ground on the 4th column? and what are the column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you are trying to count the number of repeats on the second column.. you can do it like this in mysql.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM
(   SELECT * 
    , @num:=@num+1 as col3 
    , if(@a = col2, @counter := @counter +1, @counter := 1) as col4 
    , @a := col2
    FROM 
    (   SELECT *  
        FROM
        (select (1) as col1 union select (2) union select (3) union select (4) union select (5)  order by rand()
        )t
    ) a
    JOIN
    (   SELECT * 
        FROM (select (1) as col2 union select (2) union select (3) union select (4) union select (5) union select (6) union select (7) union select (8) union select (9) union select (10)
        )c
    ) b
    ON b.col2 >= a.col1
    CROSS JOIN(SELECT @num := 0, @counter := 0, @a := 0)temp
    ORDER BY col2
) f;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c583b/65)

Comment: I don't understand what is BB at the sqlfiddle, but changing it to b.col2, it works :-)
Great! Thank you!

Comment: @olegpreobrazhenskyy you probably copied the query when I was in the middle of editing it. It you look at my most recent update and sqlfiddle there is a working copy :) glad I could help

Comment: Just as a warning:  although this answer does typically work, MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `select` clause.  What that means is that you cannot guarantee that variable assignments happen in the order you expect, and if they happen in a different order, the results may not be correct.

Comment: @gordonlindoff that is true and you can fix it by adding an order by on col2

Comment: @GordonLinoff
I know this issue. By the words. Ordering with mysql version 5.6 all works fine.
The version 5.5 of mysql sometimes gives row duplicates 'cause of unexpectable sorting alghorithm.

Comment: @JohnRuddell . . . This has nothing to do with the ordering of the *rows*.  This is about expression evaluation.  The specific warning in the documentation is:  "As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement".  (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)